# Detecting the camera that scanned image belongs to

Tags: c++, leadtools-sdk

I'm using Leadtools 20 API to control the scanner and scan some documents. I have 2 questions.
1 - When using `L_TwainAcquire` with a callback function that receives the images from the scanner and keeps returning `SUCCESS` to get the next image. Is there anyway inside the callback function to determine if the image is from the front camera or the back camera?
2 - Is there a way to force the scanner to use only the back camera for scanning?

Thank you
Sam

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you mean the 2 sides of a scanned document when using a duplex scanner, the answer is as follows:

1. To know which side of the paper is currently being processed in the bitmap callback, the following code can be used inside the callback function:

```
L_INT EXT_CALLBACK LTwainBitmapCallback(HTWAINSESSION hSession, pBITMAPHANDLE pBitmap, L_VOID * pUserData)
{
   L_INT nRet = SUCCESS;
   TW_EXTIMAGEINFO* pExtImg = NULL;
   int nExtraInfoAftreZero = 0;  // we have only one info, so no extra needed
   pExtImg = (TW_EXTIMAGEINFO *)malloc(sizeof TW_EXTIMAGEINFO  + nExtraInfoAftreZero * sizeof TW_INFO);
   if (pExtImg)  
   { 
      pExtImg->NumInfos = 1;
      pExtImg->Info[0].InfoID = TWEI_PAGESIDE;
      pExtImg->Info[0].ItemType = TWTY_UINT16;
      nRet = L_TwainGetExtendedImageInfo (hSession, pExtImg); 
      if (nRet == SUCCESS) 
      { 
         // Do processing to returned values
         if(pExtImg->Info[0].Item == TWCS_TOP)
            OutputDebugString("Front of sheet.\n");
         else if (pExtImg->Info[0].Item == TWCS_BOTTOM)
            OutputDebugString("Rear of sheet.\n");
         else
            OutputDebugString("Unexpected!\n");
         nRet = L_TwainFreeExtendedImageInfoStructure (&pExtImg); 
         if(nRet != SUCCESS) 
            return nRet; 
      }
      free(pExtImg);
   }
   return SUCCESS;
}
```

2. Forcing a specific side to scan can be done using a combination of CAP_CAMERASIDE and CAP_CAMERAENABLED capabilities, as explained in the [Twain Spec](https://www.twain.org/wp-content/uploads/2017/03/TWAIN-2.4-Specification.pdf).

Quoting from that document:

> To enable bottom only scanning, set CAP_CAMERASIDE to TWCS_BOTTOM and
> set CAP_CAMERAENABLED to TRUE, then set CAP_CAMERASIDE to TWCS_TOP and
> set CAP_CAMERAENABLED to FALSE.

If you mean you have a computer with 2 Twain camera sources (back and front), the answer becomes as follows:

1. To know which Twain source (e.g. camera) triggered the Twain Bitmap Callback when `L_TwainAcquire()` was called, you can use the
   `L_TwainGetSources()` function with the `LTWAIN_SOURCE_ENUMERATE_DEFAULT` flag to get the currently-selected Twain device. This can be done ***inside*** the Bitmap Callback as shown in the following code:

```
// Source Info Callback
L_INT EXT_CALLBACK TwainSourceInfoCallbackCurrent(HTWAINSESSION hSession, pLTWAINSOURCEINFO pSourceInfo, L_VOID * pUserData)
{
   strcpy((L_CHAR *)pUserData, pSourceInfo->pszTwnSourceName);
   return SUCCESS;
}

// Twain Bitmap Callback
L_INT EXT_CALLBACK LTwainBitmapCallback(HTWAINSESSION hSession, pBITMAPHANDLE pBitmap, L_VOID * pUserData)
{
   char szSourceName[1024];
   L_TwainGetSources(hSession, TwainSourceInfoCallbackCurrent, sizeof LTWAINSOURCEINFO, LTWAIN_SOURCE_ENUMERATE_DEFAULT, szSourceName);
   // Now szSourceName contains name of Twain Source.
   return SUCCESS;
}
```

2. Yes, you can force scanning from a specific device (scanner, camera, etc.) by sending its name to the `L_TwainSelectSource()` function before scanning, as follows:

```
LTWAINSOURCE TwainSource;
TwainSource.uStructSize = sizeof LTWAINSOURCE;
TwainSource.pszTwainSourceName = pszRearCameraTwainSourceName;
L_TwainSelectSource(twainSession, &TwainSource);
// Now L_TwainAcquire() will capture from Rear Camera
```

To find the name of all devices, you can use this code:

```
L_TwainGetSources(twainSession, TwainSourceInfoCallback, sizeof LTWAINSOURCEINFO, LTWAIN_SOURCE_ENUMERATE_ALL, NULL);
```

The Source Info Callback will be triggered once for each Twain source. It can be implemented like this:

```
L_INT EXT_CALLBACK TwainSourceInfoCallback(HTWAINSESSION hSession, pLTWAINSOURCEINFO pSourceInfo, L_VOID * pUserData)
{
   OutputDebugString(pSourceInfo->pszTwnSourceName); // You can save the names of Twain Sources into global variables if you like
   OutputDebugString("\n");
   return SUCCESS;
}
```

Comment: I think I may not have been clear enough about what I need. I know about `L_TwainSelectSource()`. It gives you the name of the selected scanner but that is **NOT** what I need. sometimes scanners have 2 cameras inside and scan both sides of the page at the same time (like Fujitsu fi-7900), and the callback gets called twice. Once for the top of paper and once for the bottom of the paper. I need to find out: 1- the callback was called for the front or back? and 2- force the scanner to only scan the backside of the page. I think it has to do with using `TWFY_CAMERABOTTOM`, but I'm not sure how.

Comment: The answer has been modified to cover your question, plus the original answer that could be useful to someone else.

Comment: Thanks for the edited answer. It kind of answered my 2nd question and pointed me `L_TwainGetExtendedImageInfo()` which might answer the 1st question. Can I use `L_TwainGetExtendedImageInfo()` inside the bitmap callback to get the page side? If yes, could you modify the answer to show how it is done? Thank you in advance.

Comment: Updated again. Sorry we didn't cover all your questions in the first edit.

Comment: Are you sure we have to free the `TW_EXTIMAGEINFO` structure twice? You are using both `L_TwainFreeExtendedImageInfoStructure()` and `free()`.

Comment: Yes we need to free 2 things. The TW_EXTIMAGEINFO structure is allocated with malloc() so we need to call free() after we’re done with it. (Or use GlobalAlloc and GlobalFree, etc.) But before freeing it, we must free the TW_INFO Info[] array inside it that gets allocated by L_TwainGetExtendedImageInfo(), so we must call L_TwainFreeExtendedImageInfoStructure() before the TW_EXTIMAGEINFO structure itself can be freed.